# Including moment-range typings in typescript project

Tags: typescript

I've recently started a new typescript project and now I want to make use of moment-range. I've installed moment-range and @typings/moment-range and I've added these lines to the top of my document:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { DateRange } from 'moment-range';
```

However, I'm still presented with this error: `Property 'range' does not exist on type 'typeof moment'`

This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom",
            "es2015.iterable"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "./node_modules/tns-core-modules/*",
                "./node_modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "platforms",
        "**/*.aot.ts"
    ]
}
```

What step am I missing?

Also, is there a way to globally include the moment range typings so that I don't have to do it in each file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I created a file like this:

```
import * as moment from "moment";
import { DateRange } from 'moment-range';

declare module "moment" {
    function range(range: string | Date[] | moment.Moment[]): DateRange;
    function range(start: Date | moment.Moment, end: Date | moment.Moment): DateRange;
}
```

I referenced it once in my main file and now I can use moment.range() anywhere

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to call range on moment itself. instead of moment-range.

if you look at their Docs on [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-range#node--npm) it says to import moment range like this:

```
import Moment from 'moment';
import { extendMoment } from 'moment-range';

const moment = extendMoment(Moment);
```

Are you extending moment? 
also what kind of project are you operating in?

Comment: the problem with this solution is that I have to execute this in every single file where I want to use moment (even when I don't need moment-range), because otherwise I can't call a function in a file without it, from a file with it.

Comment: It's an angular-nativescript project by the way

Comment: your solution is what i would recommend for angular based projects.